# SwiftUI - Using Different Transitions on Nested Views

Tags: ios, swiftui, transition

How can I have an overlaying view in SwiftUI with a different transition on different portions? E.g. in my concrete example, I want to achieve the following:

- one subview of the overlay view slides in from the bottom
- another subview of the overlay view has no transition at all (appears instantly)
- the background of the overlay does not slide in from the bottom but fades in

I've already tried all sorts of things and it seems, that I have to set animation and transition on the view that wraps the `if showOverlay` condition. However, it looks like all the `.transition()` and `.animation()` modifiers set on the sub-views of the overlay are ignored then.

Is it actually possible?
The following code is what I thought should somewhat work but apparently doesn't at all:

```
// any observable external variable, that enables / disables the overlay
@State showOverlay: bool = false

// surrounding view
VStack { /* .. */ }
  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
  .overlay(
    Group {
      if showOverlay {
        Overlay()
      }
    }
  )

// overlay view
struct Overlay: View {
  var body: some View {
     VStack {
        // style 1
        Text("OverlayContent that slides in from bottom")
           .transition(.move(edge: .bottom).combined(with: .opacity))
           .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.28))
        // style 2
        Text("OverlayContent that appears instant")
           .animation(nil)
     }
     .background( // style 3
       Color.black.opacity(0.2)
         .ignoresSafeArea()
         .transition(.opacity) // <-- background should not slide up but fade in
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: Transition works when explicit view (with transition modifier) appears or disappears... any parent or children or sibling is not related to this.

Comment: So that kind of animation I'm looking for is simply not possible except I somehow make each element that has a `.transition` inside it's own  conditional block?

Comment: @lenny Did you figure out a solution in the end?

Comment: @lazarevzubov I think the only way you could do it is to put each transition in it's distinct conditional block controlled by an individual State variable.

Comment: Hi, did yo manage to do it like you said?